# Solution of $u_{xx} + c^{2}u = 0 $ in terms of sinh.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Let $ c \in \mathbb{C}$ and
> $$
> u_{xx} + c^{2}u = 0 \ \ \text{in} \ \ (a,b)
> $$
> with $u(b) = 0$. Why
>
> $$
> u(x) = u(a)\dfrac{\text{sinh}(c(x-b))}{\text{sinh}(c(a-b))} ?
> $$

I know the above equation can be solved as
$$
u(x) = u(a)\dfrac{\text{sin}(c(b-x))}{\text{sin}(c(b-a))} 
$$
how $\sin(-y) = -\sin(y)$, then
$$
u(x) = u(a)\dfrac{\text{sin}(c(x-b))}{\text{sin}(c(a-b))} 
$$
But, why $\text{sinh}$? I know
$$
i\sin(y) = \text{sinh}(iy) \ \ \text{and} \ \ \sin(iy) = i\text{sinh}(y) 
$$
Look on page 351 for the $w$ function. Equation in relation to $w$ my question that I wrote in terms of $u$.

jstor.org/stable/pdf/24510885.pdf Page 351

Comment: That's what I can't understand. Here in the article, he makes that claim.

Comment: https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/24510885.pdf Page 351

Comment: @Gonçalo Did you understand?

Comment: @Gonçalo Look on page 351 for the $w$ function. Equation in relation to $w$ my question that I wrote in terms of $u$.

Comment: Did you miss a minus sign in front? Often the Laplace operator gets this so that in the variational equation this turns directly into a square without sign after partial integration. So the first character in $-u_{xx}+c^2u=0$ might be missing, be unreadable, you might have misread it as separator, ...

Answer (score 1):

Characteristic equation relatively of the provided differential equation will be:
$$
e^{rt}\left(r^{2}+c^2\right)=0,
\\
\left(r^{2}+c^2\right)=0,
\\
r=\pm{ic}.
$$
So our general solution will be a linear combination of our homogeneous solutions of our characteristic roots $r_1$ and $r_2$:
$$
u(x)=C_{1}e^{icx}+C_{2}e^{-icx}.
$$

Comment: Why $e^{rt}(r^{2}+c^{2}) = 0$?

Comment: But $r= =+- ic$ then $u(x) = C_{1}\cos(cx) + C_{2}\sin(cx)$?

Comment: Euler's formula is $e^{i\alpha}=\cos\alpha+i\sin\alpha.$

Comment: Then, but the solution is $u(x) = C_{1}\cos(cx) + C_{2}\sin(cx)$. How to use Euler's formula?

Comment: Therefore, we will have $u(x)=C_1\cdot\cos(cx)+C_1\cdot{i}\sin(cx)+C_2\cdot\cos(cx)-C_2\cdot{i}\sin(cx)$.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: The problem is that the function $u(x) = u(a)\dfrac{\text{sinh}(c(x-b))}{\text{sinh}(c(a-b))} $ is not a solution of $ u_{xx} + c^{2} u = 0$, since the second derivative of sinh is sinh itself.

Comment: I understand, you are right.